# LINQ Retorno da lista está com todos os registros repetidos

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, linq

Estou tendo problemas na realização de um select (usando LINQ) em uma View no SQL Server 2012.
Os valores armazenados no banco estão conforme abaixo:

```
   ID_Acomp    ID_Pessoa    Nome      Data
     26           300     MONTEIRO  01-01-2016
     27           300     MONTEIRO  02-02-2016
     28           300     MONTEIRO  03-03-2016
```

Quando realizo o select no SQL Manager, os valores retornam perfeitamente. Porém quando eu faço o mesmo select através do LINQ, o valor do ultimo registro é replicado sobre os demais registros acima, e fica assim:

```
   ID_Acomp    ID_Pessoa    Nome      Data
     28           300     MONTEIRO  03-03-2016
     28           300     MONTEIRO  03-03-2016
     28           300     MONTEIRO  03-03-2016
```

O código que estou utilizando na aplicação basicamente é este:

```
IQueryable<VW_PESSOA_ACOMPANHAMENTO> vwPessoaAcomp =  
                            contexto.VW_PESSOA_ACOMPANHAMENTO.AsQueryable();

if (ID_Pessoa > 0)
{
    vwPessoaAcomp = vwPessoaAcomp(p => p.ID_Pessoa == ID_Pessoa);
}

var retorno = (from A in vwPessoaAcomp
                 orderby A.ID_Acomp descending
                   select A).ToList();
```

Abaixo está o código da minha view:

```
SELECT A.ID_Acomp, P.ID_Pessoa, P.Nome, A.Data 
    FROM ACOMPANHAMENTO A, PESSOA P WHERE A.ID_ACOMP = P.ID_ACOMP
```

Comment: é mysql? qual a SQL que está rodando no SQL Manager? se puder poste na pergunta!

Comment: Uso o SQL Server 2012

Comment: Qual SQL você utiliza no SQL Manager?

Comment: Coloque o codigo da sua view, você pós o select do sql. Isso irá facilitar a ajuda. Você fez um debug no "retorno" para ver se gerou os registros do jeito que gostaria ?

Comment: O debug do retorno do linq sim, mas nunca fiz debug no sql manager.
Quando executo o select da view no sql manager o retorno está correto.

Comment: Vc está usando o entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo deveria funcionar perfeitamente, se estiver retornando errado provavelmente o problema está na View, nas tabelas envolvidas, ou nos dados envolvidos:

```
var vwPessoaAcomp = contexto.VW_PESSOA_ACOMPANHAMENTO.AsQueryable();

if (ID_Pessoa > 0)
{
    vwPessoaAcomp = vwPessoaAcomp.Where(p => p.ID_Pessoa == ID_Pessoa);
}

var retorno = vwPessoa.OrderBy(p => p.ID_Acomp).ToList();
```

Eu modificaria o código da view para o seguinte código, que considero mais legível:

```
SELECT A.ID_Acomp, P.ID_Pessoa, P.Nome, A.Data 
    FROM ACOMPANHAMENTO A JOIN PESSOA P ON A.ID_ACOMP = P.ID_ACOMP
```

Você poderia dar um `SELECT * FROM PESSOA` e outro `SELECT * FROM ACOMPANHAMENTO` e publicar os resultados aqui para sabermos quais dados estão envolvidos nesse caso.

Comment: O problema é que ao executar a view, os dados estão sendo exibidos perfeitamente.

Comment: @GleisonFrança o erro não está na LINQ, está em outro ponto do seu código. Você consegue criar um exemplo simples, programa console mesmo, completo e que reproduza o erro? Como também exibir os dados da sua query? Você está usando Entity Framework ou LINQ to SQL? Tente ver qual SQL está sendo emitido para recuperar os dados no banco. É até possível que sua rotina de exibição esteja fazendo algo errado. Pelo exemplo que está dando é impossível adivinhar onde está o problema.